# Why does SSLStrip work on some https sites and not others?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, sslstrip

I recently tested MITM on my LAN through SSLStrip, but I noticed that on Gmail and Fb doesn't work, while on other sites I can sniff connections easily. What is the difference?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich dang, a dupe. Could have thought so:/

Answer (score 4):

Those sites (and some more) use [public key pinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning) with [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), whereas the browser does not accept other certificates or a downgrade to http.

Comment: Milliseconds. You beat me by milliseconds.

Comment: I don't understand what is the use of the public key pinning and the reason why it would avoid the SSLstrip.